# Get data generated on another controller

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I have a simple logic problem. I'm starting on use CodeIgniter and I'm understand the Controller concept now. The view, for instance, is used only to generate content (not pre-proccess data), controller to get all infos need to view. Fine.

My problem is: I have a poll that is called as `/poll/1` from an iframe, and I like to print it in other moment on another controller. This path is relatives to `Poll::index(1)` (logically talking) and I'm on `Content::index()`.

I don't found explanation for cases like that on the [CI UserGuide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html).

How I do?

Thanks.

**Edit**: I'll do an example code:

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
    function index(){
         // Do some prints
         // Executes Poll::index(1), but store on some string
         // Do some prints
    }
}

class Poll extends CI_Controller {
    function index($id){
         // Do some prints
    }
}
```

The idea is that: `/poll/1` works and `/blog` too (but this second will print more content, with the poll).

Comment: could you add some code structure to make question bit clear?

Comment: Fine. I'll do that... wait a moment...

Answer (score 1):

hummm interesting i think using ob_start() might just work for you, if it was me i would rather use a ajax call to display poll data

here is the code.

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
    function index(){
         // Do some prints

         // Executes Poll::index(1), but store on some string
         ob_start();
            Poll::index(1)

            // You can now use this $output value to display or store in db or store in session, 
            // but remember CI session can only hold upto certain length as it uses cookie
            $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

         // Do some prints
    }
}

class Poll extends CI_Controller {
    function index($id){
         // Do some prints
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good answer, but I don't will lose the `$this` context on `Poll`? I think something like `$poll = new Poll()`, but it is valid on CI?

Comment: I haven't checked but yes in CI you will most probably loose $this my guess is calling Poll::index(1) will generate error. My suggestion is instead of creating controller for Poll, create a poll library or helper and then call it from other controllers. This way u will not break mvc pattern and will end up having cleaner code base.

Answer (score 0):

One way which is my favorite is use one as a super class  so class Poll extends blog.  This allows your poll to take advantage of your blog methods.  Then you can use any parent methods and load the proper views in which ever class#method you want.

Comment: I can't do that. I need to call some differents controllers, and not only `Poll`. As too, I will use Poll info not only on `Blog` but on other controllers.